# Should we try Topic Challenges to boost the activity?

Tags: discussion, statistics, topic-challenge

I've seen this [post](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1464/weekly-topic-challenge-ideas) on **Movies and TV meta**. 
We could have our own rules that we can define here.

I think it's a good idea and it could spice up the activity in our community. Is anyone interested?

Comment: Oddly enough, I was just thinking this *exact* thing the other day.  I have to check with the other mods and see if we can offer a prize like they do on M&TV.  Not sure if there are stickers and/or shirts yet for us as we don't have a logo.

Comment: @JohnnyBones, maybe to start, a symbolic prize could be enough (a unique badge, maybe?).

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to find out what we can do.  We're sort of the "bastard stepchildren" over here, since we're not even out of Beta after however long we've been a stack.  Maybe we can figure out a way to get the winner a bounty or something.

Comment: @JohnnyBones They don't offer a prize at all on M&TV. Neither would bounties work, since you can only award answers with bounties, not questions.

Comment: @JohnnyBones, do you have an idea about what we could do?

Answer (score 3):

#### Yes!

Topic challenges are fun. They are already on many sites, like Puzzling, Worldbuilding and Movies and work well.

Additionally, I'd give a bonus to anyone participating, like a badge. (Eg. 5 upvotes for bronze, 15 for silver, 25 for gold. Same goes for question views):

> You've earned the "Topic enthusiast badge (ask a Topic Challenge question with a score of 5 or more)"

Comment: Meta-comment: Votes on Meta mean you agree/don't agree, not the quality of the post.

Comment: You mean votes on answers?

Comment: @Bebs both answers and questions, but I'd maybe lift the answer vote count to get the badge a bit, since answers tend to get more upvotes.

Comment: So [here](http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/316/is-it-acceptable-to-ask-how-to-improve-my-own-music-and-djing), I think it is a good question, I agree *with the question* (I upvoted), but I think the answer is "no".

Comment: @Bebs you did well :)

Comment: While badges are an interesting idea, I doubt you'd get SE to actually implement any. If anything, [meta.se] might be a better place for such a proposal.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, ye gods, yes....

Anything to stop the constant useless churn of

- "What's this youtu.be link" or
- "What's that tune that goes, be-dum boom dum, ch ch-chaaah"
- "Be-doobie doo, [significant, yet barely coherent word or phrase]' oo be-dooo..'

...to which the only answers are usually "Soundhound/Shazam" or "we don't know or care"

Comment: I don't want to say "I told you", but I just did anyway. ;-)